Menu and submenu with 2 modal in laravel
I have a problem with menu and submenu calling with 2 different modal. I would like when choose in the first menu see the elements of the submenu in another modal. The problem is that I loss the variable chosen so the second modal is empty.
I report the code I'm using, below the two modal calling:
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="left:0">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-side modal-left">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Menu  Categorie principali</h5>
      </div>        
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Contenuto del menu laterale -->
        <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0 list-group dropdown"> 
    @foreach($menu as $item=>$value)
    <form action="/menu" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{csrf_field()}}
        <button class="premo btn dropdown-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" 
        data-bs-toggle="modal"  data-bs-target="#myModalSubcategories"<?=$value->menu_id?> aria-expanded="false" data-category-id="{{$value->menu_id}}">
        {{$value->menu_name}}
        </button>
    </form>
        @endforeach
      <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalSubcategories" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="right:0">
    <!-- Contenuto delle sottocategorie -->
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-side modal-left">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Menu Categorie secondarie</h5>
        </div>   
        <div class="modal-body">
    <ul>
    @foreach($submenu as $key=>$sub)   
            <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small dropdown-submenu">
            @if($categoryId ==$sub->menu_id)
            <li><a href="{{route('filter',$sub->sub_name)}}" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">
            <p>{{$sub->sub_name}} </p>
            </a></li>
            @endif
          </ul>    
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

the, use ajax for not loss the variable chosen in the first modal or first menu:
$('.premo').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var menu_value = $button.data('category-id');
    var _url='/menu';
    console.log(menu_value);

    $.ajax({
    url: _url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    'menu_value':menu_value,
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
  });

and the controller:
    public function getCategoryID(Request $request)
    {
        $categoryId = $request->input('menu_value');
     //   $categoryId = $request->input('categoryId');
        dd($categoryId );
        return response()->json(['message' => 'OK']);
    }

the console says: 500 Internal Server error. In the console, also, I can see the preview and the value in correct. I don't know the problem, but I ask you if there's another way to solve the problem

Any idea to solve the problem? Thanks.
